# accessing the header tags in an accordion using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

How can I access the header tags in an accordion. i.e Sample 1, Sample 2 and Sample 3.

I have tried using following ways for accessing with no success.

```
$("#accordion div h3 a").text()
```

or

```
alert($("#accordion div h3").text())
```

gives only last  accordion i.e.

```
alert($("#accordion div a").text())
```

gives output as clickhereclickhere...

HTML:

```
    <div id="dia">
    <div id="dialog" title="Detailed FeedBack ">
    <div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">sample 1</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#">sample 2</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="#">sample 3</a></h3>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `#accordion` is your div so all you need is this

```
$("#accordion h3 a") // <-- gets all a tags under #accordion --> h3
```

or you can just use

```
$("#accordion a") //  <-- gets all a tags under #accordion
```

depending on what your structure/requirements are

or even more specific

```
$("#accordion > h3 > a")
```

It will return an array of jquery objects which you can retrieve either using

`[index]` // <-- dom element - allows use of native dom methods

ex. `$("#accordion > h3 > a")[0]`// <-- gets first element

or

`.eq(index)`  // <-- jquery object which allows use of jQuery methods + chaining

ex. `$("#accordion > h3 > a").eq(0)` //<-- gets first element

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$("#accordion a").eq(0).text()
```

to access the text content of the first tab's link. Increment 0 for the others.